# Lubuntu 22.04. Can't remove linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic

Tags: kernel, lubuntu, dpkg

Despite seeing multiple threads here about the same problem, i couldn't follow them.

I can't install any packages, whenever i try to install something with apt install there's the same error:

```
(Reading database ... 317623 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic (5.19.0-40.41~22.04.1) ...
Failed to create symlink to vmlinuz-5.19.0-32-generic: Operation not permitted at /usr/bin/linux-update-symlinks line 64.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when i try 'sudo apt --fix-broken install' it says the same thing.

When i enter 'dpkg --list | grep linux-image' it shows:

```
ii  linux-image-5.19.0-32-generic                 5.19.0-32.33~22.04.1                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rH  linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic                 5.19.0-40.41~22.04.1                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
```

Output of 'uname -r':

```
5.19.0-32-generic
```

'sudo dpkg --purge --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic' and its variants show the same error, i tried those.

I also have a lot of unmet dependencies, but i can't solve them because everything leads to the same error! What can i do to erase the image?

Comment: "operation not permitted", like trying to make a symlink on a FAT filesystem? Do you have a separate /boot partition? Maybe you put a FAT filesystem on it instead of an ext4.  Looks like no updates to kernels have ever worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stop create symlink to vmlinuz by Editing the file `/etc/kernel-img.conf` if the file not exist create it. set the following options to the file:

```
do_symlinks = no
no_symlinks = yes
```

related

1. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1318951
2. [Issue with installing the latest linux image in lubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275595/issue-with-installing-the-latest-linux-image-in-lubuntu-20-04)

Comment: I marked your answer as completed but never replied. Thanks, this worked.